# add Item to List at creating object

Tags: c#, list

How do I create a List in a reference?

```
MyClass classA  = new MyClass();

myFuction(new List<MyClass>( ??? ))
```

How Can I add classA to that new List?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
 new List<MyClass>() {classA};
```

For collections, the elements inside the brackets will be executed using the `add` method (for "regular classes" they will be interpreted as properties)

Answer (score 3):

```
MyClass classA  = new MyClass();

myFuction(new List<MyClass>() { classA } ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple:

```
List<MyClass> classList = new List<MyClass>();
classList.Add(classA);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to inline it into the method call.

Comment: @DStanley, while true, I would prefer this method myself. Also this is the only post that is different.

Comment: This is the neater way to do it imho, but that will always be a point of discussion amongst coders.

Comment: Why write three lines of code when you can write one that's just as readable?

Comment: Because it looks a lot neater when you ulscale the

Answer (score 1):

Use [Collection initializers](http://Collection%20initializers)

```
new List<MyClass>(){classA}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also work with anonymous data like this:

```
var myList = new List<object>() { new { Location = 1, Name = "myName"}, new {Location = 2, Name = "myName2"  } }
```

saves you a couple of lines

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
MyClass classA = new MyClass();
return new List<MyClass>().Add(classA);
```

Answer (score 0):

- When a method is required to pass the list and you have only one item

  `var apps = GetApps(new List<int> { item.Id })`;
- When you have to add an item in a loop

  ```
   var appList = new List<App>();
     foreach (var savedItem in savedItems)
     {
        appList.Add(new App{ Name = savedItem.Name});
     }
  ```